# i can't debug c++ native code in android studio3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed latest LLDB cmake ndk tools and my application can successfully run on my device, but I can't set breakpoint on CPP file, I have no hybrid and auto option in "choose process" window, so I can't use lldb

[image: Img1]

And there is no debugger tab on my run/debug configuration

[image: img2]

Comment: Upgrade Android studio to 3.1 and then try debugging. It works with 3.1.

Comment: thank u guys ,i hava configured it ....check the ndk support in settings->plugin...